# Парсинг xml simple_xml

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser, simplexml

Есть такая структура xml

```
<text>
   sometext sometext <bold>bolded text</bold> sometext <bold>bolded text</bold>
</text>
```

Обрабатываю так:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($str);
$text = $xml->xpath("//text");
```

Так значение $text = sometext sometext sometext

А нужно чтобы значение было всем текстом внутри (т.е. вместе с `<bold>`).

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать, опыта работы с simplexml очень мало.

Comment: `normalize-space(//text)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но если можно, напишите полностью как это выглядит в xmlpath.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="<body><text>sometext sometext <bold>bolded text</bold> sometext <bold>bolded text</bold></text></body>";

$xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
$text = $xpath->query("//text");

echo $text->item(0)->nodeValue;

// sometext sometext bolded text sometext bolded text
```

Comment: Все равно выводится вместе с внут. тегами http://prntscr.com/9g3dgp

Comment: Подождите, так вы внутренние тэги хотите сохранить, а не только их содержимое?